# Zend 2 : How to use a method defined in another model in my current model?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, tablegateway

I try to solve this problem in different ways, but seems nothing is working. 
I have 2 models:

```
namespace Admin\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class UsersMetaTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function saveData(UsersMeta $value)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function getAttachment($user_id){
        $user_id  = (int) $user_id;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('parent_id' => $user_id,'meta_key' =>'inside_users_attachement'));
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (!$row) {
            return false;
            exit;
        }
        return $row->meta_value;
    }   
}
```

And my current Model:

```
namespace Admin\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class AttachmentTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function saveData(Attachment $value)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function getAttachment($user_id)
    {
        $user_id  = (int) $user_id;

        //HERE I NEED TO LOAD UsersMetaTable MODEL AND USE  getAttachment METHOD

        $attachment_id = $usersMetaTable->getAttachment($user_id);

        if($attachment_id){
            $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('ID' => $attachment_id));
            $row = $rowset->current();
            if (!$row) {
                return false;
                exit;
            }
            return $row;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In `AttachmentTable` model I need to use the method `getAttachment` from the `UsersMetaTable` model. How can I do that in Zend Franework 2?

My two models are defined in `Modele.php`:

```
public function getServiceConfig(){
    return array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(),
        'aliases' => array(),
        'factories' => array(
            'Admin\Model\AttachmentTable' =>  function($sm) {
                            $tableGateway = $sm->get('AttachmentTableGateway');
                $table = new AttachmentTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'AttachmentTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new attachment()); // Notice what is set here
                return new TableGateway('attachments', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
            'Admin\Model\UsersMetaTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('UsersMetaTableGateway');
                $table = new UsersMetaTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'UsersMetaTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new UsersMeta()); // Notice what is set here
                return new TableGateway('inside_users_metas', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ),
        'invokables' => array(
        // defining it as invokable here, any factory will do too
            'my_image_service' => 'Imagine\Gd\Imagine',
        ),
        'services' => array(),
        'shared' => array(),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject your `UsersMetaTable` into your `AttachmentTable` in the factory like this:

```
'Admin\Model\AttachmentTable' =>  function($sm) {
    $tableGateway = $sm->get('AttachmentTableGateway');
    $usersMetaTable = $sm->get('Admin\Model\UsersMetaTable');
    $table = new AttachmentTable($tableGateway, $usersMetaTable);
    return $table;
},
```

And then you need to update your constructor so it puts the injected service in place:

```
namespace Admin\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class AttachmentTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    protected $usersMetaTable;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway, UsersMetaTable $usersMetaTable)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
        $this->usersMetaTable = $usersMetaTable;
    }

    // ...remaining class code
}
```